# Increment integer between two numbers to create the smoothest line

Tags: math, linear-programming

I'd like to make a formula/function/algorithm to calculate the smoothest line between two sets of numbers.

```
Set1: (214,224,238)  
Set2: (180,207,226)
```

Consider the above two sets as being pairs.

```
214-180  
224-207  
238-226
```

I believe the first step is to get the smallest difference between each set of pairs. In this case it is 12 as 238 - 226 = 12. We could then increment 12 times for the other two pairs.

```
214-180 = 34.  
34/12 = 2.83333333   
214 - (2.83333 * 12) = 180
```

If the problem allows us to have decimals, it's quite straight forward. The problem is that we cannot have a decimal. Each value must be an integer. Therefore in this example, 10 iterations will reduce by 3 and 2 iterations will reduce by 2.

As for smoothness, it would make sense that the 2 - 2 iterations should be spaced between the 3's equally. Thus the pattern would be

```
3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3. 
211, 208, 205, 203, 200, 197, 194, 192, 189, 186, 183, 180
```

Hopefully I've explained thoroughly. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: Why not just calculate in floating point and then round? The `i`-th value would then be `round(start + i/n * (end - start))`, where `n` is the total number of steps.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Well, I think you answered it.. If you want to post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) intended for drawing lines on integer grid.
Algorithm distributes steps on the whole range.

[image]

Perhaps it might be appropriate in your case.

Dictinct from your approach: you are using the smallest coordinate difference while this algo - the largest one -  to reach claimed purpose - "the smoothest line".